# How to record video in ProRes codec on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation, avcam

I would like to capture video from device’s back camera directly to ProRes codec, now that `.proRes422` and `.proRes4444` are available as `AVVideoCodecType` options in iOS 11.

But I receive an error that recording is:

> unsupported given the current configuration

On both iPhone X and second generation iPad Pro, when trying to capture video with the following code:

```
movieFileOutput.setOutputSettings([AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.proRes422], 
                                  for: movieFileOutputConnection!)
```

If this approach is wrong, can the captured video be encoded by using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` alongside `AVAssetWriter`?

Comment: As far as i know ProRes422 is only supported on Mac OS X

Comment: @ErikTerwan [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocodectype/2875383-prores422) explicitly states that ProRes 422 is supported on iOS 11.0+ and tvOS 11.0+.

Comment: @ErikTerwan As is [ProRes 4444](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocodectype/2875384-prores4444).

Comment: The symbol being available on those platforms is not the same as the configuration being supported at runtime. What does `-availableVideoCodecTypes` return on your devices?

Comment: @Tim For `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, on both the iPhone X and iPad Pro 10.5”, it returns HEVC, H.264, and Motion JPEG.

Comment: @Tim Why would Apple mark these symbols as supported if they are completely useless?

Comment: @Boletrone there's a difference here between "available" and "supported." Just because iOS is aware of the existence of a format, and has named it using a symbol, doesn't mean that it immediately supports everything to do with the format. It could support decoding but not encoding; it could support offline editing, but not capture; or support might be planned for a future release.

Comment: @Tim Turns out you were right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I received a response from Brad Ford, an engineer from camera software team at Apple:

> The `AVVideoCodecType` (string) is available, meaning you can compile
>   code that references this constant without a compile error. But
>   `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` is telling you the truth. ProRes is not
>   supported on iOS.