# iPad Pro M2 model ProRes video recording

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I have the following code to determine ProRes and HDR support on iOS devices:

```
extension AVCaptureDevice.Format {

  var supports10bitHDR:Bool {
     let mediaType = CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaType(formatDescription)
     let mediaSubtype = CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType(formatDescription)
     return mediaType == kCMMediaType_Video && mediaSubtype == kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr10BiPlanarVideoRange

   }

   var supportsProRes422:Bool {
      let mediaType = CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaType(formatDescription)
      let mediaSubtype = CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType(formatDescription)

      return (mediaType == kCMMediaType_Video && (mediaSubtype == kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr10BiPlanarVideoRange))
   }
}
```

However, on iPad Pro with M2 chip, `supportsProRes422` is returning false for every format in array `device.formats` (for the default wide angle camera). Is this an AVFoundation bug or something intentional? How do I enable ProRes recording on iPad Pro M2 device?

Comment: Please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47651412/how-to-record-video-in-prores-codec-on-ios

Comment: @Wo_0NDeRᵀᴹ I don't think that question is much relevant.